# How can I perform a logical test to ensure that MY CUSTOM ERROR gets thrown instead of the NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

I am working on something that should be fairly simple. I have 95% of my program working, but one piece is still not fulfilling the requirement. (FYI, this is for a homework assignment, but I will prove that I have put good effort into it before coming here.)

The piece of the assignment:
* The ProductionWorker class should throw an exception named InvalidPayRate when it receives a negative number for the hourly pay rate or if the data entered is not numeric.

I have my InvalidPayRate logic for catching negative numbers, but I am not too sure how to ensure that the input is numeric. Here is the relevant code:

InvalidPayRate.java

```
public class InvalidPayRate extends Exception {
    public InvalidPayRate(){
        super("Error: Invalid Pay Rate.");
    }
}
```

ProductionWorker.java

```
void setHourlyPayRate(double rate) throws InvalidPayRate
    {
        if (rate < 0.0){
            throw new InvalidPayRate();
        }

        this.hourlyPayRate = rate;
    }
```

test.java (this is within a main function)

```
//Set Rate details
try{
    worker.setHourlyPayRate(-15.00);
    System.out.println(worker.getHourlyPayRate() + ": Valid HourlyRate");  
} catch (InvalidPayRate e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

try{
    worker.setHourlyPayRate(20.00);
    System.out.println(worker.getHourlyPayRate() + ": Valid HourlyRate");  
} catch (InvalidPayRate e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

String testRate = "1v2.65";
try{
    double rate = Double.parseDouble(testRate);
    worker.setHourlyPayRate(rate);
    System.out.println(worker.getHourlyPayRate() + ": Valid HourlyRate");  
} catch (InvalidPayRate e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Right now, 2 of the 3 tests are working... the Valid entry, the negative number entry (returns my custom error) but my non-numeric entry is not working... it gives the standard NumberFormatException error.

How can I perform a logical test to ensure that MY CUSTOM ERROR gets thrown instead of the NumberFormatException?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue, but is too old to migrate to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown from `Double.parseDouble`, in other words outside of your code, by the time `setHourlyPayRate` gets called you know it's a valid double. The conversion from string to double is *not your problem*™.

If you really want to throw your custom exception then you need to wrap the conversion in a try catch and rethrow the custom exception:

```
String testRate = "1v2.65";
try{
    double rate;
    try{
        rate = Double.parseDouble(testRate);    
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new InvalidPayRate();
    }
    worker.setHourlyPayRate(rate);
    System.out.println(worker.getHourlyPayRate() + ": Valid HourlyRate");  
} catch (InvalidPayRate e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

There is one input you don't guard against though and that is `Double.NaN` which you can test for with `Double.isNan`.

```
if (Double.isNaN(rate) || rate < 0.0){
    throw new InvalidPayRate();
}
```

Comment: Did you answer his question, or is this just a code review?

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and the addition of handling non-inputs. I still don't know why I am receiving that error then... if it isn't from trying to convert String testRate = "1v2.65"; to a double.

Comment: @Wescrock the error *is* from trying to convert a String to a double, but it happens before `setHourlyPayRate` is ever called. and most of the time that can be handled in the UI before even touching the `ProductionWorker` class

Comment: When I try your above example, it won't compile due to "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: InvalidPayException.<init>
 at employee.Test.main(Test.java:80)
Java Result: 1"

Comment: @Wescrock sorry I expect that all exception classes end in `Exception` so force of habit after writing `throw new`

Comment: Since the question states *"The **`ProductionWorker`** class should throw an exception named InvalidPayRate"*, I believe `setHourlyPayRate()` should be overridden to take a `String` as well.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Ugh, that was my bad too... i should have caught that! What you posted worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: by convention, all subclasses of Exception are named Exception, so it should be InvalidPayRateException.